# How to Block installing another app in android devices?

Tags: kiosk-mode

I want an Android device like mobile phones with no mobile features in it like no camera,no calling facility no sound nothing...

I just want a touchscreen device with android operating system so that i can install my own app and i dont want any other app should get install in it... only my app would be there...

can anyone pls tell me how can i do this....

or is it possible to stop all the services of our android cellphone so that when i switch on my mobile phone directly my app should be visible....

please reply .......

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking for is [tag:kiosk-mode], so I've added that tag to your question. Take a look at the existing questions with that tag and see if any of them help you. If they do, then either answer your own question with what you did, or flag your question as a duplicate of one of the existing ones, so future visitors can see what the outcome was. If they don't, just edit your question to say why the existing suggestions won't work for you, and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

*"i don't want any app to get installed on it..."*

Technically this is impossible, since there are *system apps* like `SystemUI` and `framework-res` that Android needs to actually function.

But if you are talking about non-essential apps *only*, then perhaps you can delete them with root. Go to `/system` on a file manager that supports root, e.g. X-plore and Root Explorer, and delete the apps that you think are safe to delete. Be careful though, as those apps are on the `/system` partition and not `/data` for a reason. Your phone might become unstable after this.

The list of safe apps varies per manufacturer, but remember, *Google is your friend!*

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Wifi ONLY tablets fit your requirement of "no calling facility" but they have sound and some have camera.

Google is coming up with project ara, here is the link http://www.projectara.com
This project specifically targets people who wants to customize their mobile phones just like "assembling components in desktop pc". For example:- if you want to remove the camera, you can simply remove that particular module alone.

But Android might not be compatible with such configuration as of now. May be in coming months, probably in a year or two you might be able to do all that.

In some countries they have managed to remove google services and install their own yandex, nokia has done the same with one of their models, amazon has done something similar with android.